Trying to reload ExoPlayer with new video after button click
In my code, I'm basically giving the user a screen with an exoPlayer and a button to get new video. I'm trying to make my exoPlayer reload with new video after the user clicks the button, but I cannot do it properly. Please review my code and let me know what I'm doing incorrectly.
After the button click, my videoplayer is playing the same video as before. Getting back and forth to the screen gives the user the proper video on the player.
Maybe exoPlayer.setMediaItem(ms) and exoPlayer.prepare() should execute before VideoScreen() is recomposed, but I don't know how to achieve this.
Short version below. Full version: https://pl.kotl.in/Utv39DIQJ
@Composable
fun VideoScreenRoute() {
    var videoUriState by remember { mutableStateOf<String?>(null) }
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        val result = getNewVideoUri()
        videoUriState = result; Log.d(TAG, "result: $result")
    }

    var mediaSource = remember(videoUriState) {
        val newUri = videoUriState; Log.d(TAG, "new uri: $newUri")
        if (newUri != null) MediaItem.fromUri(newUri) else null
    }
    LaunchedEffect(mediaSource) {
        val ms = mediaSource
        exoPlayer.setMediaItem(ms); Log.d(TAG, "mediaItem set")
        exoPlayer.prepare(); Log.d(TAG, "player prepared")
    }

    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    VideoScreen(
        exoPlayer,
        mediaSource,
        onGenerateBtnClicked = {
            scope.launch {
                generateVideo()
                videoUriState = getNewVideoUri()
            }
        }
    )

    DisposableEffect(Unit) {
        onDispose {
            exoPlayer.release()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun VideoScreen(
    exoPlayer: ExoPlayer, mediaSource: MediaItem?, onGenerateBtnClicked: () -> Unit
) {
    Log.d(TAG, "mediaSource: $mediaSource")
    if (mediaSource != null) {
        AndroidView(
            factory = { ctx ->
                PlayerView(ctx).apply {
                    player = exoPlayer
                }
            }
        )
        exoPlayer.play()
    }
    Button(onClick = onGenerateBtnClicked) {
        Text(text = "Generate new video")
    }
}

Logs after navigating to VideoScreenRoute and clicking button:
new uri: null
mediaSource: null
result: /storage/emulated/0/Movies/LapseLab/eee/eee-2images-2024-09-06-12-39-07-848.mp4
new uri: /storage/emulated/0/Movies/LapseLab/eee/eee-2images-2024-09-06-12-39-07-848.mp4
mediaSource: androidx.media3.common.MediaItem@708c9dda
mediaItem set
player prepared
mediaSource: androidx.media3.common.MediaItem@708c9dda
mediaSource: androidx.media3.common.MediaItem@708c9dda

*** Button clicked ***

New video: success!
new uri: /storage/emulated/0/Movies/LapseLab/eee/eee-2images-2024-09-06-12-41-11-030.mp4
mediaSource: androidx.media3.common.MediaItem@5226628c
mediaItem set
player prepared

